# git push always assumes the wrong user

Tags: git

I used several github accounts in the past. Now somehow, git push always defaults to one of the username. I am not able to change it even if I do

git config user.name

I went thru quite a few stackoverflow pages on this topic. Tried erasing github_rsa files, and so on. None helped. So I always have to declare the username in the git url right now to do a git push.

Can someone help me thru this? tell me what to look for. I will post what I have.

Comment: Have you tried git config --global user.name "UsernameHere"

Comment: check what the credentials are in your git config

Comment: `git push` simply delivers the URL to a URL-helper of some sort, and the URL-helper winds up providing the credentials, if any, to the remote at the other end of that URL. Hence this depends first on the URL. If the URL begins with `http://` or `https://` the helper depends on your OS; if it begins with `ssh://` it is less OS-specific as it is always ssh, but ssh's details can become OS-specific as well. So the first thing is to specify the URL and your OS.

Answer (score 1):

If `git push` isn't asking for your username, then it's using a key somewhere. Github just uses the key to work out which account you're pushing to - you don't actually specify the username anywhere. So you need to find the key (probably in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`) and delete it.